# How to search a table tr based on two values

Tags: jquery

I have a table and a search input .

When User Types something in the input , i need to show relevant information related to the value  entered inside the search input

User can search either  by **company name** or **ceo name**

```
 // if user enters TCS or Chandran ,i need to show TCS table row
    $("#search").keyup(function(){
        _this = this;
        $.each($(".portlet"), function() {
            if($(this).data('compname').toLowerCase().indexOf($(_this).val().toLowerCase()) === -1)
               $(this).hide();
            else
               $(this).show();                
        });
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cod7ceho/173/

Could you please let me know how to fix this

Comment: in the fiddle, there's no table, just divs and lists. There are no `tr` elements anywhere. Nor are there any elements with a `data-compname` attribute. Did you write this code? It bears absolutely no relation to the example HTML. Not surprising it doesn't work.

Comment: There is  a main table which starts with 
<table id="results" and under it the the first parent div consists of data-compname="TCS" data-ceo="Chandran"

Comment: yes, there's a table. but there are no `tr`s which is what you're trying to search for. And the only valid element within `tbody` is `tr`. You shouldn't put divs in there. Your HTML is invalid.

Comment: okay , please check the updated fiddle , how to filter based on two conditions right now its working only for company name , how to include ceo name also ?

Comment: simplest way is just to add an "and" clause to the if statement. If the search phrase does not appear in either of the fields, then hide the div.

Comment: you mean this way http://jsfiddle.net/cod7ceho/175/ which isn't working for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added one more condition:

```
if((($(this).data('compname').toLowerCase().indexOf($(_this).val().toLowerCase())) === 0)||($(this).data('ceo').toLowerCase().indexOf($(_this).val().toLowerCase())===0))
```

Check out this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/cod7ceho/177/

Comment: Pleasure. Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

You only want to hide 'rows' if you can't find the search string in both `compname` AND `ceo`, so you should add

`&& ($(this).data('ceo').toLowerCase().indexOf($(_this).val().toLowerCase()) === -1)` to your `if`

like so:

`if(($(this).data('compname').toLowerCase().indexOf($(_this).val().toLowerCase()) === -1) && ($(this).data('ceo').toLowerCase().indexOf($(_this).val().toLowerCase()) === -1))`

this gets a bit hard to read so I would also reformat to:

```
if(
    ($(this).data('compname').toLowerCase().indexOf($(_this).val().toLowerCase()) === -1)
    && ($(this).data('ceo').toLowerCase().indexOf($(_this).val().toLowerCase()) === -1)
){
    $(this).hide();
} else ...
```

Comment: Thanks but  getting Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &&

Comment: that's probably a bracket issue, your `if` may now look like
`if (yourstatement) && (mystatement)`
when it should be
`if ((yourstatement) && (mystatement))`

Answer (score 0):

You could use JQuery [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/), for example:

```
$("#search").keyup(function() {
  _this = this;
  inputVal = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
  console.log(inputVal);
  if (inputVal === "") {
    $('.portlet').fadeIn();
  } else {
    $('.portlet').filter(function() {
      return $(this).data('compname').toLowerCase().indexOf($(_this).val().toLowerCase()) !== -1;
    }).fadeIn();
    $('.portlet').filter(function() {
      return $(this).data('compname').toLowerCase().indexOf($(_this).val().toLowerCase()) == -1;
    }).fadeOut();
  }
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cod7ceho/182/

Comment: what do you mean? I've tested and it seems fine... it filters the company name,but you can also modify to filter by the CEO aswell.

Comment: Could you please provide a sample fiddle

Comment: [http://jsfiddle.net/DouglasCamargo/cod7ceho/176/](http://jsfiddle.net/DouglasCamargo/cod7ceho/176/)

Comment: yes, but as I said, if you want to filter by the CEO as well you need to change the code a bit... but it shouldn't be a problem for you  ;)

Comment: but, of course, this is not the complete code, it's just a possibility... you can refine it to suit your needs...

Answer (score 0):

I went following way:

```
$("#search").keyup(function(){
   _found = false;
   _this = this;
    $.each($(".portlet"), function() {
        if($(this).data('compname').toLowerCase().indexOf($(_this).val().toLowerCase()) == -1) {
           $(this).hide();
           _found = false;
       } else {
           $(this).show();
           _found = true;
       }

       if($(this).data('ceo').toLowerCase().indexOf($(_this).val().toLowerCase()) == -1 && _found == false)
           $(this).hide();
        else
           $(this).show();
    });
});
```

I added the variable `_found` as a state holder and additional condition. Properbly not the best way, it's just working.